# Building own smart dns-proxy with powerdns and Squid to socks5

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, proxy, squid, powerdns

I want to build my own small smart dns-proxy server with following features:

1. Client sets DNS Server like (2.2.2.2 <- MY DNS Server includes Proxy Squid)
2. Client sends request for sepcial domains (youtube.com etc.)
3. DNS responses: 2.2.2.2 (my proxy server)
4. My proxy is now connecting to another-location-proxy: 3.3.3.3:6060 (SOCKSv5)
5. My Proxy is getting the content which is requested and sends only this back to the client.

So my goal is to send only this specific request to the SOCKS Proxy.

Is it possible with the software powerdns and squid for example?

Thanks.

Comment: technically, you can, with PowerDNS [recursor](https://doc.powerdns.com/recursor/index.html) and Squid, but with the advent of HTTPS, doing client HTTP proxy is difficult if not impossible without breaking SSL/TLS chain-of-trust. technicality aside, is there any reason you wanted to implement this?

Comment: so maybe you have some keywords here or some right config variables in pwdns / squid for the first help? 
this is for the purpose of using a video portal in swiss, so im using a SOCKS proxy located in swiss. it works fine with the http / socks implemented in firefox for example.
-The security ascpect is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just found a shell script on github which fully fulfills its purpose with squid sslbump, sniproxy and dnsmasq installed. (Instead of powerdns).

1. Cloning https://github.com/suuhm/unblock-proxy.sh
2. Setting my wished SOCKS Proxy in the proxies file.
3. Running in bash to start the smartdns:

```
./unblock-proxy.sh dns --squid --debug
```

This solution works for me